# Load one time beside the $(document).ready(...) ? Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with triggering a function which needs to be loaded only one time.But I don't want to put it into:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

});
```

I want to run it separate.

I have tried:

```
 jQuery(document).one(function () {
        myfunction();
    });
```

and some other stuff.
But couldn't solve it.

**UPDATE:**

I have my webservice on ready():

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    PageMethods.myWebSer(suc, fail);
});

function suc(){
//I want to run my function here , but only one time
//Examplle
 //jQuery(document).one(function () {
          //  myfunction();
       // });
}
```

Thank You

Comment: Where _do_ you want to _'put'_ it? ie. when should it run, timing wise? `onready`, `onload`, _whenever_?

Comment: Actually it's going to be outside, it will be run on another function.

Comment: What do you mean by separate? When do you want this function to be called?

Comment: I'm gonna update my question

Comment: Do you want to run `myfunction` only once, or `suc` only once.

Answer (score 2):

Just add another `ready` or `load` function : you may have as many as you want, they will all be called in order :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   // this will be run
});
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   // and this one too (after the other one)
});
```

Comment: Be sure to emphasize that the `ready` event is only fired once. OP doesn't seem to understand that.

Answer (score 1):

It you want it to run `onload` use:

```
jQuery(window).load(function () {
    // run
});
```

Keep in mind that `ready` fires *before* `load`.