# Javascript: Run a function only once including partial postbacks

Tags: javascript, jquery, postback

I have a page where i need to load data to cache on window.onload event, which is done by async call using jquery ajax as show below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload=loadcache();

    function loadcache(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "/AsyncCache/LoadCache",
            async: true,
            ...
        });
        }
    }
</script>
```

This caching works fine, but the page has few partial postbacks, so on each postback the function *loadcache()* is called and that worries me.

**Approaches tried:**

Moved the ajax call to *$(document).ready* still the function *loadcache()* is called on each postback.

I know this question is repeated several times in this forum, but i was unable to get an answer, referring to some of the question below:

[Load one time beside the $(document).ready(...) ? Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15277220/load-one-time-beside-the-document-ready-jquery?answertab=votes#tab-top)

[Only fire an event once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393686/only-fire-an-event-once)

How can i use Jquery.one for above scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You can just unattach the event when the load function is executed, and you'll be safe.
Hope this helps:

```
function loadcache() {
  ...

  window.onload = null;
}
```

Comment: I tried the above window.unload = null in the function, it still calls loadcache() function on partial postback, thanks for the reply